# Creating a sql view with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view, inner-join

I currently have three tables Engineer, Classes, and Faculty. I am trying to create a view that will display Engineer firstname and lastname, Classes subject and title, and Faculty lastname and email. All under one view I've tried multiple different ways but still can't figure out how to properly execute

```
CREATE VIEW RETRIEVAL
SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname, b.flastname, b.email, c.subject, c.title
FROM engineer a 
INNER JOIN faculty b ON a.lastname = b.flastname
INNER JOIN classes c on c.cid = b.fid;
```

Comment: You TAGGED `JOIN` but you dont use it ??

Comment: **1)** Use the Alias's on the column list so the compiler knows which table to get those 2 lastnames from **2)** Add an alias to at tleast one of the `lastname` columns so you actually see 2 seperate columns

Comment: Why are you trying to create a view?

Answer (score 0):

[Edited after clarifications were provided by the asker]

It looks like you want to do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT e.firstname, e.lastname, e.email, f.lastname, c.subject, c.title
FROM engineer e 
   INNER JOIN faculty f ON e.faculty_id = f.id
   INNER JOIN classes c on f.id = c.faculty_id
WHERE c.subject > c.title
```

This is if you have an `id` field in faculty and a `faculty_id` field in classes.
Also a faculty_id in `engineer`

However I'm not sure I understand what do you want to achieve with the `c.subject > c.title` condition as it is not mentioned in the question.

This would work for a many-to-one relationship between `engineer` and `faculty`.

If there's a many-to-many relationship between `engineer` and `faculty` then you need an additional table `engineer_faculty` where you store the relationships between the two and update the query accordingly

Before committing to create the `VIEW`, run the `SELECT` by itself and see if it shows the results that you want. If it does, then create the view.

Try providing some example data on https://www.mycompiler.io/new/sql
We could then be of better help.

Comment: You have dropped one of the `lastname` columns, Both are required if you look at the question, instead give it an alias like `b.lastname as faculty_lastname`

Comment: If you actually look the question states ___I am trying to create a view that will display Engineer firstname and lastname, Classes subject and title, and Faculty lastname and email___ See specifically `and Faculty lastname`

Comment: Engineer.lastname = Faculty.lastname. It does not make sense to select the same value twice from different tables.

Comment: You make a good point, but that was not what was asked for :)

Comment: No, but the question is overall unclear so it doesn't make sense to provide a potential answer with that kind of error in it just because it was asked. If someone asks me for a square circle I'm not going to provide it :)

Comment: Understanding the question isn't perfectly clear. The engineers and faculty are two unrelated tables therefore last names are different in both I did change one of them to flastname so that actually makes them different now but now I get no rows selected

Comment: No, its not an error. Its quite legitimate to have a column in 2 tables with the same name, and the way round the select is to give at least one of them an alias so both will show

Comment: It's not about having the same name. It's about having the same value.

Comment: If as @BrxaanJ mentioned the values are not the same, then why are you using the condition `a.lastname = b.flastname` This means that the rows will only be selected when the two values are equal.

Comment: @BrxaanJ Since the values are not equal, then you cannot use them for the join. You need to `join` on equal values. something like `a.faculty_id = b.id`

Comment: And you don't need to rename the fields of the tables. You can have columns with the same name in different tables as long as you take that into consideration when you are selecting them. Something like `a.lastname, b.lastname AS faculty_lastname`

Answer (score -1):

You should use the aliases you gave to the tables in the FROM cluase as you did in the WHERE clause:

```
CREATE VIEW RETRIEVAL AS 
SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname, b.lastname, b.email, c.subject, c.title
FROM engineer a, faculty b, classes c
WHERE a.lastname = b.lastname 
      AND c.subject > c.title;
```

Comment: I'm getting a duplicate column name which is because of the lastname column from engineer and faculty

Comment: `b.lastname as faculty_lastname`